Should spam links be edited out?
When users see obvious spam posts, as well as flagging them as spam, should they edit out the spam links too?
I've seen various discussions in comments about whether to do this or not.
I have a fairly strong opinion which I will leave as an answer, but phrasing as a Q&A to allow for a debate.

As a moderator, I would prefer people don't do this. Leaving spam posts untouched:

makes it more likely other people will also flag as spam leading to the post being deleted quickly
makes it easier for moderators to spot spam and hence take action quickly
makes it easier for moderators reviewing multiple posts by a suspected spammer (that were maybe already deleted) to verify that the user is spamming consistently
is general network policy (confirmed by a staff member)

